# Implementing Twitter Profile Widget

Tags: jquery, twitter, widget

Is there anyway to load the twitter profile widget in a dom ready case or something similar? Everytime I seem to wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$(function(){});` it breaks.